# What's a clean way to sort these separate-but-related sequences in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have two `vector` objects that contain different types of data that are ordered in the same way. My situation looks something like this:

```
struct Info
{
    double opaque_data_not_relevant_to_this_problem[6];
    int data_len;

    bool operator<(const Info &rhs) const
    {
        return (bool) irrelevant_operation_on_opaque_data;
    }
};

vector<Info> vec1;
vector<double> vec2;
```

For each `Info` entry in `vec1`, `vec2` contains a sequence of `double` values, equal in length to the value of `data_len` in the corresponding element in `vec1`. For example:

```
vec1[0].data_len == 100 ==> vec2[0:99] correspond to vec1[0]
vec1[1].data_len == 150 ==> vec2[100:249] correspond to vec1[1]
// and so on
```

I understand that this arrangement is not very OO and there is probably a "more C++" way to do this. However, other constraints in my environment force me toward this type of data packing, so I need to work around it. Unfortunately, the length of each data record in `vec2` (specified by its `data_len` counterpart in `vec1`) are not known until runtime, and the length varies from record to record.

My problem: I would like to sort the two vectors by some criteria. Sorting `vec1` is simple, as I can just use `std::sort`. At the same time, however, I need to sort `vec2` such that the ordering described above is still maintained (i.e. the first block of values in `vec2` corresponds to `vec1[0]` after it is sorted). It would be nice if I could get some kind of "index vector" out of the sorting process that I could then use to reorder `vec2` (in-place or out-of-place operation would be fine), but I'm not sure of a good way to do that with the standard library (if there is one).

I could do the sort by defining a second intermediate structure that bundles the two together:

```
struct SortableInfo
{
    Info info;
    vector<double> data;

    bool operator<(const SortabelInfo &rhs) const { return info < rhs.info; }
};
vector<SortableInfo> vec3;
```

I would then populate `vec3` appropriately based on the contents of `vec1` and `vec2`, sort it, then fan the data back out to separate vectors again. However, this doesn't seem particularly efficient. Any suggestions on a better way to execute this?

Comment: Could you store a vector of pairs of iterators from the two vectors and sort it based upon the first iterator?

Comment: To be clear: are you allowed or not to modify the definition of `Info`?

Comment: @Rob: Thanks, I just realized that I should clarify that. **No**, I cannot change the definition of `Info`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store in your `SortableInfo` pointers to the start positions in the corresponding `vec2`

```
struct SortableInfo {
    Info info;
    double *start_pos;

    bool operator<(const SortabelInfo &rhs) const { return info < rhs.info; }
}
```

populate your `vec3`, sort it and then at the end make an ordered copy of your `vec2` using the sorted pointers.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that; this is why I love Stack Overflow. I think my final solution will treat `SortableInfo` as a "view" into the two vectors; both of its members are pointers into the two arrays. I then sort the list of `SortableInfo` objects, then dereference their members as needed to iterate through the sorted sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the specific constraint that causes you to bundle your data that way is, but your `vec3` option is close to the object oriented way of doing things.

What I would do, is to just make 1 vector, of your struct(or class depending on your needs) in the first place, and forget about the separate vectors in the first place.

Is there a particular reason why you can't do this?

Comment: I don't have any control over the input data format; I'm receiving it from another module that I cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a offset in Info ?

```
struct Info
{
    int data_len;
    int offset;
    bool operator<(const Info &rhs) const
    {
        return (bool) irrelevant_operation_on_opaque_data;
    }
};
```

offset is just the offset in your vec2
so now you can have for example

```
vec1[0].offset = 350, vec1[0].data_len = 100 ==> vec2[350:450] = your data
```

If you also want to support delete you have to redefine all your `offset` and this solution might not be that efficient.

Now you can just sort and still use your `offset` to find the data.

---

Just define a new Struct and use it as a wrapper.

```
struct ExtendedInfo
{
    Info info;
    int offset;
}
```